# Replace the spaces between multiple (3+) capital letters

Tags: r, regex, gsubfn

I have some text where people use capitals with spaces in between to make the substring standout.   I want to replace the spaces between these substrings.  The rules for the pattern is: "at least 3 consecutive capital letters with a space between each letter".

I'm curious how to do this with pure regex but also with the *gsubfn* package as I thought this would be an easy job for it but in MWE example below I crashed and burned as an extra letter was placed in there (I'm curious why this is happening).

### MWE

```
x <- c(
    'Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!',
    'Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed.'
)

## first to show I have the right regex pattern
gsub('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', '<FOO>', x)
## [1] "Welcome to A I: the best <FOO>!"               
## [2] "Hi I R is the <FOO> for sure: we <FOO> indeed."

library(gsubfn)
spacrm1 <- function(string) {gsub('\\s+', '', string)}
gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', spacrm1, x)
## Error in (function (string)  : unused argument ("L ")
## "Would love to understand why this error is happening"

spacrm2 <- function(...) {gsub('\\s+', '', paste(..., collapse = ''))}
gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', spacrm2, x)
## [1] "Welcome to A I: the best WORLDL!"               
## [2] "Hi I R is the BOMBM for sure: we AGREEE indeed."
## "Would love to understand why the extra letter is happening"
```

### Desired Output

```
[1] "Welcome to A I: the best WORLD!"                 
[2] "Hi I R is the BOMB for sure: we AGREE indeed."
```

Comment: The regex has two capture groups but the function in the first `gsubfn` call only has one argument.  It should have one argument for each capture group, i.e. two arguments.  Try this to see what it is passing: `gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', ~ print(list(...)), x)`

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the mismatch in the number of arguments. If you use `spacrm2` with `gsubfn('((?:[A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', spacrm2, x)` the result is as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you give as an answer

Comment: Ah, I recalled at last: to be able to pass the whole match, you need to pass the `backref=0` argument.

Comment: https://ideone.com/dx1ZGJ

Comment: @ClasG can you put that down as a formal answer...nice logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments the problem in the first gsubfn call in the question arises from there being two capture groups in the regex yet only one argument to the function.  These need to match -- two capture groups implies a need for two arguments.  We can see what gsubfn is passing by running this and viewing the print statement's output:

```
junk <- gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', ~ print(list(...)), x)
```

We can address this in any of the following ways:

**1)** This uses the regex from the question but uses a function that accepts multiple arguments. Only the first argument is actually used in the function.

```
gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', ~ gsub("\\s+", "", ..1), x)
## [1] "Welcome to A I: the best WORLD!"              
## [2] "Hi I R is the BOMB for sure: we AGREE indeed."
```

Note that it interprets the formula as the function:

```
function (...) gsub("\\s+", "", ..1)
```

We can view the function generated from the formula like this:

```
fn$identity( ~ gsub("\\s+", "", ..1) )
## function (...) 
## gsub("\\s+", "", ..1)
```

**2)** This uses the regex from the question and also the function from the question but adds the backref = -1 argument which tells it to pass only the first capture group to the function -- the minus means do not pass the entire match either.

```
gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', spacrm1, x, backref = -1)
```

(As @Wiktor Stribiżew points out in his answer `backref=0` would also work.)

**3)** Another way to express this using the regex from the question is:

```
gsubfn('(([A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z])', x + y ~ gsub("\\s+", "", x), x)
```

Note that it interprets the formula as this function:

```
function(x, y) gsub("\\s+", "", x)
```

Comment: All great answers...this was the first answer for the check

Answer (score 10):

### Overview

There is a way in R to do this using regex entirely, but it's not pretty (although I think it looks pretty sweet!) This answer is also customizable to whatever your needs are (two uppercase minimum, three minimum, etc.) - i.e. scalable - and can match more than one horizontal whitespace characters (doesn't use lookbehinds, which require a fixed width).

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/sHRvm1/3)

```
(?:(?=\b(?:\p{Lu}\h+){2}\p{Lu})|\G(?!\A))\p{Lu}\K\h+(?=\p{Lu})
```

Replacement: Empty string

---

### Edit 1 (non-ASCII letters)

My original pattern used `\b`, which may not work with Unicode characters (such as `É`). The following alternative is likely a better approach. It checks to ensure what precedes the first uppercase character is not a letter (from any language/script). It also ensures that it doesn't match an uppercase character at the end of the uppercase series if it is followed by any other letter.

If you also need to ensure numbers don't precede uppercase letters, you can use `[^\p{L}\p{N}]` in the place of `\P{L}`.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/sHRvm1/5)

```
(?:(?<=\P{L})(?=(?:\p{Lu}\h+){2}\p{Lu})|\G(?!\A))\p{Lu}\K\h+(?=\p{Lu}(?!\p{L}))
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/gKoDsj)

```
x <- c(
    "Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!",
    "Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed."
)
gsub("(?:(?=\\b(?:\\p{Lu}\\h+){2}\\p{Lu})|\\G(?!\\A))\\p{Lu}\\K\\h+(?=\\p{Lu})", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!
Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed.
```

#### Output

```
Welcome to A I: the best WORLD!
Hi I R is the BOMB for sure: we AGREE indeed.
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:(?=(?:\b\p{Lu}\h+){2}\p{Lu})|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `(?=\b(?:\p{Lu}\h+){2}\p{Lu})` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches (used as an assertion in this case to find all locations in the string that are in the format `A A A`). You can also add `\b` at the end of this positive lookahead to ensure something like `I A Name` doesn't get matched

    - `\b` Assert position at a word boundary
    - `(?:\p{Lu}\h+){2}` Match the following exactly twice

      - `\p{Lu}` Match an uppercase character in any language (Unicode)
      - `\h+` Match one or more horizontal whitespace characters
    - `\p{Lu}` Match an uppercase character in any language (Unicode)
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `\p{Lu}` Match an uppercase character in any language (Unicode)
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\h+` Match one or more horizontal whitespace characters
- `(?=\p{Lu})` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is an uppercase character in any language (Unicode)

---

### Edit 2 (python)

Below is the python equivalent of above (it requires [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to run). I replaced `\h` with `[ \t]` as PyPi regex doesn't currently support `\h` token.

[See the working code here](https://tio.run/##JY3BigIxDIbP9il@e7FlZQ7rbUAGZUVlXQQvHqwHR6MWdFo6HXYX9dnHaBNIafIln/@PZ1cN2tZevQsRgU70J3YYYiPAIdd02bsrITqMMM8Rz4SS6og1llhhga@u7Cd0ZjHnlq3f0JjnP1yPLqBuAuX4JT4xZWLCaasD0SGTYitEYN1bnLHK2wupIFWRq2JoSn6Nvy2axwYmbj/07fOR/vpupqrompHWqWG@E/JaS4TU4mW3LMMuFx0fbBVVyOqmVL1e32rdtk8)

```
import regex
a = [
    "Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!",
    "Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed."
]

r = regex.compile(r"(?:(?=\b(?:\p{Lu} +){2}\p{Lu})|\G(?!\A))\p{Lu}\K +(?=\p{Lu})")
for i in a:
    print(r.sub('',i))
```

Above regex based on first regex. If you're looking to use the second regex, use this:

```
(?:(?<=\P{L})(?=(?:\p{Lu}[ \t]+){2}\p{Lu})|\G(?!\A))\p{Lu}\K[ \t]+(?=\p{Lu}(?!\p{L}))
```

#### Using a callback

Please see [Wiktor's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47437191/3600709) regarding callbacks, this is simply a ported version of his R program into python. This doesn't use the PyPi regex library and so it won't match. Also, this won't match Unicode.

```
import re
a = [
    "Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!",
    "Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed."
]

def repl(m):
    return re.sub(r"\s+",'',m.group(0))

for i in a:
    print(re.sub(r"(?:[A-Z]\s+){2,}[A-Z]", repl, i))
```

Comment: Amazing...wouldn't have come to this on my own.  Great learning here.

Comment: I have been trying to replicate this in python, but unfortunately havn't made much headway. @ctwheels, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Raqib I've added an edit to my answer to include the python variant

Comment: @chtwheels. Thank you so much for helping out. Additional question, is there a way to do this purely using the python's inbuilt re library? I am trying to avoid using third party libraries as much as I can but if that is the only solution, then I am content with using the library. Thank you again, you saved. me fair amount of headache.

Comment: @Raqib you may be able to use a callback, I added a new edit to Edit 2, but it won't work with Unicode. You'd have to create your own parser for Unicode as default `re` library doesn't have Unicode classes so `\P{Lu}` won't work. You'd have to implement that code-side using `islower()` and `isdigit()` to identify Unicode variants and change the regex to `(?:[^\W_]\s+){2,}[^\W_]` + use `re.UNICODE` to ensure matching of Unicode chars

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is what items are passed to the `spacrm` functions by `gsubfn` and the mismatch in the number of arguments `spacrm` function accept and the number of arguments passed to them.

See the [`gsubfn` docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/gsubfn.pdf) about `backref` argument:

> Number of backreferences to be passed to function. If zero or positive the match is passed as the first argument to the replacement function followed by the indicated number of backreferences as subsequent arguments. *If negative then only the that number of backreferences are passed but **the match itself is not.*** If omitted it will be determined automatically, i.e. it will be 0 if there are no backreferences and **otherwise it will equal negative the number of back references**. It determines this by counting the number of non-escaped left parentheses in the pattern.

So, in your case, the `backref` argument was omitted, and the `spacrmX` functions [got `W O R L D` and `L`](https://regex101.com/r/5v5M15/1)  values.

The  `spacrm1` function that only accepts a single argument got two arguments, hence the `unused argument ("L ")` error.

When `spacrm2` was used, it got all two captured values, and they got concatenated (after whitespace removal).

You may actually just use `backref=0` to tell the `gsubfn` to  only handle the whole match value and simplify the pattern, remove capturing groups and use one non-capturing instead:

```
spacrm1 <- function(string) {gsub('\\s+', '', string)}
x <- c(
     'Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!',
     'Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed.'
)
gsubfn('(?:[A-Z]\\s+){2,}[A-Z]', spacrm2, x, backref=0)
[1] "Welcome to A I: the best WORLD!"              
[2] "Hi I R is the BOMB for sure: we AGREE indeed."
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply match a space preceded by a capital letter, as well as followed by two capital letters separated by a space (using look-arounds). **Or the other way around** - match a space preceded by two capital letters separated by a space, and then followed by a capital letter.

```
(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z] [A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z] [A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])
```

R-code:

```
x <- c(
    "Welcome to A I: the best W O R L D!",
    "Hi I R is the B O M B for sure: we A G R E E indeed."
)
gsub("(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z] [A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z] [A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

[Live here at ideone](https://ideone.com/dx1ZGJ).